# Sum of a square and a cubic module a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it the case that for prime number $p$ and any $a$, there always exist $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^3\equiv a \pmod p$. I think this is true, but want to see a clear proof. Moreover, is there any general theory behind this type of question?

Comment: elliptic curves?

Comment: this is what I thought, but do not know the detail.

Comment: If I remember right, I asked essentially this question and the answer was "yes". This is one of the reasons why elliptic curves are so hard to solve.

Comment: @Peter. yes, I think the answer is yes, but is there a proof?